# ¿Cómo se puede obtener la dirección hacia la que se dirige el usuario en Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

¿Cómo se podría obtener con la API de Google Maps JavaScript la dirección hacia la que se dirige el usuario?. Con "dirección" me refiero a los cuatro puntos cardinales (Norte/Sur/Este/Oeste).

Comment: Hola @Gonher. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Probaste solucionarlo por tu cuenta investigando en la web? Quizás sería de mayor utilidad [edit] la pregunta mostrando un poco de código para aclarar qué estás haciendo, qué buscaste y qué te está trayendo problemas. La guía [ask] puede ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Toma el punto en el que se encuentra el usuario en un momento (con [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)) y guárdalo (lo llamaremos `desde`).
2. Pasado un tiempo, toma el nuevo punto donde se encuentra el usuario (lo llamaremos `hasta`)
3. Realiza los cálculos que quieras sobre esos datos para obtener información como distancia, velocidad, dirección, aceleración (si guardas un histórico de localizaciones)...

   > Nota: Ten en cuenta que los resultados que obtengas serán siempre aproximados. Piensa que la Tierra no es plana, hay cambios de altura, el usuario puede no seguir una línea recta entre ambos puntos, etc. Hay muchos factores que afectarán los resultados.

   En tu caso particular, quieres calcular la dirección. Con la API de Google Maps, podrías hacerlo fácilmente usando la biblioteca de geometría (sólo tienes que añadir `libraries=geometry` como parámetro a la URL donde cargas la API) y el método [`computeHeading(desde, hasta)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings). Dependiendo del valor que obtengas (que oscilará entre [`[-180 y 180)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical)) sabrás hacia dónde va la persona:

   - -180: sur
   - (-180 a -90): sudoeste
   - -90: oeste
   - (-90 a 0): noroeste
   - 0: norte
   - (0 a 90): nordeste
   - 90: este
   - (90 a 180): sudeste

   > En el segundo enlace (el de `computeHeading`) puedes ver un ejemplo que hace los cálculos que quieres; mueve los marcadores para ver cómo el valor del ángulo cambia.